# No first row from query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This query doesn't show only first row, others work fine. It was working 2 days ago, and it was fine. I dont rememeber that i have changed code in a past days.

```
        $query='SELECT * FROM cv.users
                LEFT JOIN cv.users_goal on users.user_id =  users_goal.user_id
                LEFT JOIN cv.users_info on users.user_id =  users_info.user_id
                LEFT JOIN cv.users_images on users.user_id =  users_images.user_id
                WHERE users.user_id ='.$user_id.';';


        $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo'<div class="cv-info-field cv-field">
                    <div class="cv-info-name">'
                        .$row['user_name'].' '.$row['user_surname'].'
                    </div><div class="cv-info-imgwrap">
                        <img class="cv-info-img" src="'.$row['user_image'].'">
                    </div>'
                    .$row['user_profession'].
                   '<div class="cv-info-userdata">'.$row['user_mobile'].'</br>'
                        .$row['user_email'].'</br>'.$row['user_pc'].'</br>'.$row['user_country'].' - '.$row['user_city'].' - '.$row['user_adress'].'
                    </div>

                </div>
                <b>Goal:</b>
                <div class="cv-goal-field cv-field">'
                    .$row['goal'].
                '</div>';
        }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `mysql_query($query)` twice?

Comment: My bad. But still doesnt work

Comment: 1) small suggestion, Use "  " in query 2) ` symbol for field name and table name

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. You need to make sure the query is actually returning the proper dataset by running your query from the command line or in a tool like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @KarthikKeyan That won't make a difference

Comment: @John I am one time suffer this problem i have used this ` symbol form field name to solve the problem
just the suggestion

Comment: @KarthikKeyan adding ticks to the column names won't affect this query

Comment: @john Surely not affect the query

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0,1' at line 5

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM `cv.users`
                LEFT JOIN `cv.users_goal` on `users.user_id` =  `users_goal.user_id`
                LEFT JOIN `cv.users_info` on `users.user_id` =  users_info.user_id
                LEFT JOIN `cv.users_images` on `users.user_id` =  users_images.user_id
                WHERE `users.user_id` ='.$user_id.' ";

Comment: Its very strange, I havent changed anything

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Maybe your provider upgraded your PHP version.

Comment: @DimonVersace after you code do this: `print_r(error_get_last());` to show the error.

Comment: What error do u got ?

Comment: you need to update your question with the code you are now using, seeing you were using `mysql_query()` twice.

Comment: 'Array ( [type] => 8192 [message] => mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead [file] => D:\Software\XAMPP\htdocs\diplomka\pages\etc\DBconnect.php [line] => 3 )'

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.